# How to seal/shutdown a subversion repository

Tags: svn

My project switched from svn to mercurial. I need to shut down/seal the svn repository so nobody commits to it mistakenly anymore. I do not want to shut down the svn server as there are still other projects using it.

My google-fu is failing me. How do I do this?

Comment: Tell the developers to stop using it?

Comment: Don't be silly, there's a way to shut down the repository explicitly.

Comment: You could also change the permissions on the directory where that repo is stored.

Comment: See if this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228183/subversion-is-it-possible-to-disable-all-commits-and-make-the-repository-read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a pre commit hook in `./hooks/pre-commit` (chmod +x of course)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Use the mercurial repository for new code please" 1>&2
exit 1;
```

Comment: Damn you beat me to it. sys.stderr.write ("Use the mercurial repository for new code please.\n")
        sys.exit(1)